# Class methods & thread safety (NSJSONSerialization)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, thread-safety

In my iOS app, I am doing some work in a background thread (using `performSelectorInBackground`). In this thread, I am using NSJSONSerialization and its class methods to parse a JSON string:

```
self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:0 error:nil];
```

Is this class method (`JSONObjectWithData`) thread safe? Can I be sure about this? Where is it written in the documentation?

I know that instance methods are generally *not thread-safe* unless the docs say they are. Can I generally say that class methods *are thread-safe*, unless specified otherwise?

Comment: Best way is to make parallel operation on [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:] call, and see if you have reentrancy problem. If nobody tells you it's thread safe, then it's not thread safe ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that the document describing thread-safety has not been updated to show `NSJSONSerialization`. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

Comment: You want to use self.json, if you make it thread safe then will it work?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit guessing here.

The [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) states

> Immutable objects are generally thread-safe; once you create them, you
>   can safely pass these objects to and from threads.

Calling a class method means sending a message to the class object, and class objects are immutable. My conclusion would be that it is safe to call class methods from different theads.

Comment: Unless the class method involves global state, which can be difficult to determine.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a similar question on the Apple developer forum. The response I got was that NSJSONSerialization is thread-safe:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11229

Answer (score -1):

Managed content is not thread safe. You could either run the code on your mainthread or run it in the background and use NSNotificationCenter to start reloading your UI when the background thread is done processing.

Comment: The question (as I understand it) was whether it is safe to call `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:...]` from multiple threads simultaneously, not about modifying the UI from a background thread.